# InvocationException while viewing object while debugging in java

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, lombok, targetinvocationexception

I am not able to see the values of the object in debug and it show InvocationException.

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the code snippet by which I am trying to get the data from DB as previousObject by repository.getById(passing the Key from the mappedObject) which is mapped to the FundRequest Entity Class.

```
final FundRequest mappedObject = requestToEntityMapper.map(requests, entityClass.FundRequest);

final JpaRepository<U, Object> repository = repositoryStrategyProvider.getRepository(repoType);

Storable previousObject = null;

try {
     ----> previousObject = repository.getById(mappedObject.getKey()); <-----
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("error: " + e);
}
```

FundRequest Class is as below. Is it something to do with the Lombok & Hibernate annotations?

I am using @Data, @Entity.
Now according to this article : [Here](https://thorben-janssen.com/lombok-hibernate-how-to-avoid-common-pitfalls/) I tried Removing @Data annotation and tried with @Getter @Setter, but still it throws the  same exception

```
package com.abhishekpandey.jsonWriterReader.domain;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Entity;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;


@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name="FUND_REQUEST", schema="MYFUNDDB")
public class FundRequest implements Storable {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "DESC_CD")
    private String descriptorCode;

    @Column(name = "AREA_CD")
    private String areaCode = "A";

    @Column(name= "ACCT_CD")
    private String accountingCode = StringUtils.EMPTY;

    @Column(name = "FUND_CD")
    private String fundCode = StringUtils.EMPTY;

    @Column(name = "LOAD_STAT_C")
    private Short loadStatusCode = 1;

    @Column(name = "USER_I")
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "MOD_TS")
    public Timestamp lastUpdated;

    @Column(name = "CREATION_TS")
    public Timestamp createdAt;

    @Override
    public String getKey() {
        return String.valueOf(descriptorCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a bit more detail, simply with a POJO, its difficult to comment on the cause of the exception

Comment: Looks like issue with `final JpaRepository<U, Object> repository = repositoryStrategyProvider.getRepository(repoType);`. Please check the class of this. Is it returning you the correct object.

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala Yes it returns me the FundRequest repo object.  I have added the variables info. It gets the values, but doesn't show them.

Comment: Please check the class, may be a mapping / conversion is going for a toss

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala Here mappedObject & previousObject are of same Class Objects. The data coming from DB is getting mapped only in the FundRequest.class.

When I hover over mappedObjects it shows the values but not for the previousObject

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243463/discussion-between-abb-and-saurabh-jhunjhunwala).